# Cross site scripting issue with "ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');"

Tags: apex

I got Cross site scripting error from 'Security scan report' for following method in Apex code:

```
String myId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
```

I tried to find another solution for this, but did not get any solution.
There is solution that, when you access parameter from 'VF page' but i did not find any solution when we access it from 'Apex code'.

If any one know the solution for this problem, please let me know.